# Why deleting item from redux it delete all item in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux to keep tracking of the cart item and the following is the reducer:

```
const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 

       switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_TO_CART':
                return [...state, action.payload]
            case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
                return state.items.filter(i => i.Id !== action.payload.Id);
    
        }
        return state
    }
```

and the action creator as follow:

```
 const removeItemFromCart = item =>
        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
            payload: item
        })
```

and within the cart screen I am rendering an array they is structured as follow:

```
 [[{"Id": 875, "name": "Burger", "photo": "https://apicms.thestar.com.my/uploads/images/2020/02/28/579752.jpg", "total": "25.00"}],[{"Id": 865, "name": "Burger", "photo": "https://apicms.thestar.com.my/uploads/images/2020/02/28/579752.jpg", "total": "20.00"}],[{"Id": 888, "name": "Burger", "photo": "https://apicms.thestar.com.my/uploads/images/2020/02/28/579752.jpg", "total": "22.00"}]]
```

so when I press one delete button for specific item it delete all items in cart but I want to delete only that item

Answer (score 0):

In your array, you have array brackets for each item, either remove those extra array brackets or use the 0th index of each item to filter like the code below.

```
state.items.filter(i => i[0].Id !== action.payload.Id)
```

To add items to the cart try pushing the payload inside states.items

Comment: "To add items to the cart try pushing the payload inside states.items" may i know how to do this please

Comment: use state.items.push(payload)

Comment: You cannot use a mutating operation like `push` inside a reducer unless you are using an immutability helper like Redux Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a key to your array like **cart** because you could have more data like price and you will need to give it a key.

```
       const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 
       switch (action.type) {
            case 'ADD_TO_CART':
                return {...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]}
            case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
                return {...state, cart: state.cart.filter(i => i.Id !== action.payload.Id)};
    
        }
        return state
        }
```

Comment: i got this error `  TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.` and then deleted all item

Comment: I added this state.items.filter instead of state.cart.filter, which state.items isn't an array.  I updated my code, it should work.

Comment: I updated my code, I changed this line state.items.filter instead by state.cart.filter by.

Answer (score 0):

You are very confused about the shape of your state.

- The data that you get in the cart screen is an array of arrays where
  each one has a single item.  Either your `addToCart` action creator is incorrect or you are calling it incorrectly.
- `case 'ADD_TO_CART'` treats the state as an array of items.
- `case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART'` treats the state as an object with a property `items` that is an array of item objects.  Instead of returning a new state with an updated `items` property, you just return an array.  So this case is really bad because it's incompatible with itself.

---

If you want the state to just be an array of items then your `case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART'` should `filter` the entire `state`.

```
const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case "REMOVE_FROM_CART":
      return state.filter((i) => i.Id !== action.payload.Id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

Redux is much easier to work with using the official Redux Toolkit because you don't need to worry about mutating state.  The [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) function in particular is great because it automatically creates action creators for each case in the reducer.  Check out [the tutorials](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/overview) and docs to understand why this code works.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload);
        },
        removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
            return state.filter((i) => i.Id !== action.payload.Id);
        }
    }
})

// action creators
export const {addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart} = cartSlice.actions;
// reducer
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: thank you for that, i have followed what you suggested me to use redux toolkit but same problem i am facing again as it delete all item

Answer (score 0):

const cartSlice = createSlice({
name: "cart",
initialState: [],
reducers: {
addItemToCart: (state, action) => {
state.push(action.payload);
},
removeItemFromCart: (state, action) => {
return state.filter((i) => i.Id !== action.payload.Id);
}
}
})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).